# Cygwin Python 2.7 package

Tags: python, cygwin

I'm on Windows trying to run a Python script. The problem I'm facing is that this script requires Python 2.7. Cygwin is currently installed with the Python 2.6 package. I tried searching for a 2.7 package in the installation wizard but couldn't find any. So I'm kinda stuck. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: What feature of 2.7 isn't available in 2.6?

Comment: import argparse
ImportError: No module named argparse

Comment: lack of dict comprehension in 2.6 just caught me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had downloaded a corrupt package of the source code. I tried it again and it worked fine.

The solution to this problem is to compile the package yourself till its not officially available. I had downloaded a corrupt package of the source code, md5 checksum turned out to be different. I tried it again and it worked fine.

Answer (score 9):

[image: python 2.7.3-1]

Running setup.exe for Cygwin will give you the chance to upgrade Python to 2.7.

If you don't see the 2.7 package, go back and select a different mirror, since not all repositories have all versions available.

Comment: in latest cygwin i don't see option fro 2.7. and I want it to run google app engine.

Comment: I have the latest also, I run setup.exe, hit next six times (choose all defaults), type Python in the Search box, expand the Python tab and it offers me 2.7.3-1 as the latest version to install

Answer (score 7):

Install python 2.7 from python.org or EPD, etc. Then put the location of python.exe (default is `C:\Python27\python.exe` ) in your Environment Variables (Right click "Computer" from `start menu -> select "properties" -> Environment Variables` )

and remove python 2.6 from cygwin, before you do all this.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply :) but now i have downloaded the source code for python 2.7 . Now the problem I m facing is ./configure gets stuck at

Comment: hmm so how will cygwin have access to python 2.7 then ?

Comment: yes.. that's how I use python 2.7. But the unix-specific modules will not work. Other than that everything is fine.